# Can a VIP be used in front of secured Kafka clusters?

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos

Has anyone been successful putting a vip in front of kafka clusters which are kerberized and over ssl/tls?

(known to work without Kerberos)

The goal being to route a client to a different kafka cluster without them needing to know the broker names of both clusters.

Through testing the closest to success found was using advertised listeners. even in that case it only succeed when the machine reached just happened to be the leader of the topic at the time the connection was made.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don't know about Kafka specifically, but generally you can put any load-balancer in front of clustered servers and setup a Virtual Name (VIP) which the LB then accepts all inbound traffic for and routes to the specific set of servers you have set up behind that.  You then configure that VIP in DNS as part of an SPN so when Kerberos-aware clients search for the SPN, their traffic is sent to the LB, and then ultimately to the servers behind it, in your case, Kafka.  Companies do this kind of setup all the time.

Comment: Yes we put the VIP name in as the SPN which allows the secure connection during the fetch cluster metadata but then during the send the VIP appears to be what the client uses which may or may not be the topic leader and that seems to be the sticking point. How to use VIP for metadata but then use machine name for send if only one SPN (either VIP or machine name) can be in the JAAS?

Comment: The LB should be able to handle all this.  What kind of LB do you have?

Comment: F5 LTM but it does not appear to be a routing problem as much as a security, specifically Kerberos, problem.